# Make eloquent query filtered by a result of this query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I try to get events from my database

```
$eventWithDatas = Event::with(['persons' => function($query) {
            $query->select('persons.id', 'name', 'title', 'status')
                    ->where('date_of_death', null);
        }, 'persons.health_items' => function($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name', 'date_in', 'date_end', 'person_id');
        }])->get();
```

I would like to filter my relationship `persons.health_items`.

The ideal would be to have something like that :

```
$eventWithDatas = Event::with(['persons' => function($query) {
            $query->select('persons.id', 'name', 'title', 'status')
                    ->where('date_of_death', null);
        }, 'persons.health_items' => function($query) use ($eventWithDatas) {
            $query->select('id', 'name', 'date_in', 'date_end', 'person_id')
                    ->where('date_end', $eventWithDatas->end);
        }])->get();
```

`$eventWithDatas` should be the first part of my query (`Event::get`)

Example with result:

```
[
{
  / event collection (contain just 1 item for example)
  "title": "vaccines",
  "start": "2020-07-24 01:00:00",
  "end": "2020-07-24 01:00:00", // <----------- I WANT TO USE THIS DATA FOR FILTER persons.health_items.date_end (see bottom)
  "persons": [
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Jeremy",
     ...
     "health_items": [
        {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "my health item",
          "date_end": // <-------------------- DATA TO FILTER (see top) (2020-07-24 01:00:00)
        }
      ]
   ]
}
]
```

Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: I undeleted my answer after making some fixes. Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: U can`t achive expected result with "with" function, U should use "join"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to your [constrained eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) approach is to join to the events table, so we can compare the date_end and end fields. Assuming you have many-to-many persons to events, you can do this as follows:

```
Event::with(['persons.health_items' => function($query){
    $query->select('health_items.*')
          ->join('persons', 'persons.id', '=', 'health_items.person_id')
          ->join('event_person', 'event_person.person_id', '=', 'persons.id')
          ->join('events', 'events.id', '=', 'event_person.event_id')
          ->whereRaw('`health_items`.`date_end` = `events`.`end`');
}])->get();
```

Comment: Hello ! I just tried your solution. Unfortunately, I still get all the possible "health_items" results. They are not sorted by `events.end`, it seems to have no effect. It does not generate a bug but it does not solve my problem. I get `health_items` with a` date_end` different from `events.end`

Comment: Did the version of the solution you tried have $inner->whereRaw('health_items.date_end = events.end'); because I updated it 15 minutes ago. Before it was $query->whereRaw

Comment: I have updated my solution, to use the constrained eager loading approach from your question. Hope it helps!